# Forecast Function in Excel

Tags: excel, forecast

I have 2 columns:

[image]

I need to forecast the value of X. Excel gives me errors when I try using the FORECAST formula.
I've tried this and the inverse
=FORECAST(B4,A2:A4,B2:B3)  Assuming Number is X and Date is Y. I'm also willing to flip it (Number is Y, Date is X)

Does anyone know how to use the FORECAST formula to forecast the next value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With forcast the value you are looking for is always the y so the related values are the Y's.

You put in the known Y's (B2:B3) and known X's (B2:B3).  These ranges must be the same size and shape.  B4 is not part of the known X's it is the value you want to test, or the first Criterion in the formula:

```
=FORECAST(A4,B2:B3,A2:A3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Scott. Will give this a shot in a few and let you know.

Comment: Just tried and it works exactly as I need it to. Thanks